# Java NoSuchElementException while using resourceloader to load the textfile

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream, nosuchelementexception

[im using resource loader to save the file into jar file (click here to open the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfx3O.png)

[it is working perfectly fine is i remove the while(f.hasnext() { .... }
I couldn't figure out what is going wrong I am trying to load the text file into jar file so, I am reading it through inputstream (click here to open the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY74k.png)

[this is the text file which i am loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgBq5.png)

### main

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      ArrayList<morse> mkey = new ArrayList<>();
      encription e = new encription();

            morse.load(mkey);


 }


}
```

### ResourceLoader

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    final public class ResourceLoader {

    static ResourceLoader rl = new ResourceLoader();

    public static InputStream rload(String path) {
        InputStream input = rl.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);

        return input;
    }
    }
```

### morse

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
final public class morse {

    String c;
    String symbol;
     public static void  load(ArrayList<morse> mkey) throws FileNotFoundException
     {      
         Scanner f = new Scanner( ResourceLoader.rload("morse key.txt"));
         int i=0;
        while(f.hasNext()) {
            morse temp =new morse();

            temp.c =f.next();
            temp.symbol = f.n;
            mkey.add(temp);
            System.out.println(mkey.get(i).c  );
            //f.nextLine();
            i++;

        }
         f.close();      
     }

}
```

### textfile

0 -----
1 .----
2 ..---
3 ...--
4 ....-
5 .....
6 -....
7 --...
8 ---..
9 ----.
a .-
b -...
c -.-.
d -..
e .
f ..-.
g --.
h ....
i ..
j .---
k -.-
l .-..
m --
n -.
o ---
p .--.
q --.-
r .-.
s ...
t -
u ..-
v...-
w .--
x -..-
y -.--
z --..

Comment: Hmm. `temp.c = f.next();`  then once again `temp.symbol= f.next();`  (following further in the stream). are you sure this is correct? (I don't know the stream well enough and the rest of the code)

Comment: I am adding the text file which I'm reading from

Comment: you can call f.next() in that while loop ONLY once and have it guaranteed there will be a next element

Comment: if I can use f.next only once how should use next string to load into temp.symbol?

Comment: first and foremost if you're going to have to copy and paste your code here if you want more help as i will have to work with it. then `f.next()` is going to read a string in, and my guess is that its reading in that entire line.

Comment: So, you edited your code. Still giving problems?

Comment: i edited the code it is not giving any problem if i am having only one f.next() statement in the loop.

Comment: but i have to get both the string into the class object how am i suppose to do that .

Comment: what is `encription` its not used, also dont make everything static

Comment: theres a lot of design level problems with this, and i cant write your project for you, if someone has the time, they may, but theres a lot to do here

Comment: thank you, it worked if I used the f.nextline() and saved it into a string and modified the string later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I originally wrote in the comments, instead to call f.next() twice, just read the entire line once and split the string into temp.c and temp.symbol .